# Find the city which a name most repeated

Tags: sql, postgresql, select

I have two tables:

table_1: id, name (DEFAULT 'JACK')

table_2: id, city

I link them with "id" and insert some data into them like:

```
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(1, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(2, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(3, DEFAULT);
INSERT INTO table_1 VALUES(4, DEFAULT);


INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(1, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(2, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(3, 'Paris');
INSERT INTO table_2 VALUES(4, 'Berlin');
```

I added 3 JACK into Paris above, I need to traverse it somehow to get the city that has the most JACK name in it. How can I do it?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using? MySQL or PostgreSQL?

Comment: @Mureinik Sorry, i added the PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rank` to rank the cities by number of jacks and then take the top one:

```sql
SELECT city
FROM   (SELECT city, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY cnt DESC) AS rk
        FROM   (SELECT   city, COUNT(*) AS cnt
                FROM     t1
                JOIN     t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
                WHERE    name = 'Jack'
                GROUP BY city
               ) x
       ) y
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Comment: Sir can you please explain what the most inner SELECT do?

Comment: @newbienUser The inner select counts the number of jacks per city. The middle one assigns ranks to those cities based on the number of jacks and the outer one selects the city or cities with the top rank

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.name, t2.city, COUNT(t1.name) FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
GROUP BY t2.city, t1.name;
```